# cannot find module cv2 in opencv3.0

Tags: python, opencv

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 system, on which I want to install OpenCV 3.0 and use it with Python 2.x.

Here is my cmake command:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE 
      -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local 
      -D WITH_TBB=ON 
      -D WITH_V4L=ON  
      -D WITH_OPENGL=ON 
      -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON 
      -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON 
      -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON 
      -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 
      -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 
      -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 
      -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON ..
```

The result after the cmake

```
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.6)
--     Libraries:                   NO
--     numpy:                       /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.10.0)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3.4 (ver 3.4)
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
```

after the installation, When I try to run the sample Python script, I get the following:

```
$ python opencv.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "opencv.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cv2.cv import *
ImportError: No module named cv2.cv
```

Others who get this import error after install seem to be having a path issue, and have luck adding this to their code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

However it doesn't work for me ,since the site-packages folder is just a empty folder.